# guard desugaring

Tags: haskell, syntax, syntactic-sugar, guard

I often hear the phrase, guards are just syntactic sugar for if-then-else (or case statements).

Can somebody please desugar the following instance:

```
halfOf :: Int -> Int
halfOf x | even x = div x 2
```

(The function is intentionally partial)

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The semantics of pattern matching are defined in the following section of the standard: [Formal Semantics of Pattern Matching](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/exps.html#case-semantics).

The step that is relevant to your question is c. As you can see, pattern matches with guards of the form

```
case v of { p | g1 -> e1 ; ...
              | gn -> en where { decls }
            _     -> e' }
```

Are translated to pattern matches without guards as:

```
case e' of
{y ->
   case v of {
       p -> let { decls } in
            if g1 then e1 ... else if gn then en else y ;
        _ -> y }}
```

So pattern guards are defined in terms of `if` and "fallthrough" is implemented by binding the expression to a variable and then repeating it once in the `else` clause of the `if` and then in the pattern that you'd fall through to.

If there is no case to fall through to (as in your example) one will have been inserted by step b, which inserts a default case `_ -> error "No match"`

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I'd love to be able to mark a branch as pattern matching error, but I can see why such a functionality is not offered by the language. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

```
halfOf x =
  if even x
  then div x 2
  else error "Incomplete pattern match"
```

The exact kind of error triggered by an unhandled case is not specified by the language definition, and varies from compiler to compiler.

**edit**: If there are multiple guards and/or patterns, each guard or pattern match goes into the non-matching part of the previous case.

```
compare x y
  | x == y = foo
  | x /= y = bar
compare _ _ = baz
```

produces

```
compare x y =
  if x == y
  then foo
  else if x /= y
       then bar
       else baz
```

Comment: yaha! there is a problem here. this is not a pattern matching error.  what happens if there is another case after this line?

Comment: @Ozgur: If you want a complete answer don't try and bait people with intentionally mis-worded questions.

Comment: @Ozgur: See http://cs.anu.edu.au/Student/comp1100/haskell/tourofsyntax.html#Guards

Comment: oops sorry. no trolling intended. i am just trying to understand something here. really.

Comment: This answer is correct, except the message would be 'Program error: {sign 0}'.

Comment: @Ozgur: My apologies if your question was sincere. It just helps if you include as much information as possible (including approaches you may have already tried).

Comment: @Akusete: I thought the message would be implementation dependent. What I am looking for is not a magical way to guess the compiler generated message, rather tell the compiler a branch of the if-then-else represents a pattern matching error, somehow.

Comment: @Ozgur: I see your point, unfortunately I dont have an answer. :). +1 question

Comment: btw, thanks for the obvious answer @Heatsink. since I didn't mention it in the original question, someone had to point it out. sorry for polluting the comments part of your answer though :)